# Disable a UIButton when a sound is playing AVAudioplayer

Tags: ios, audio, uibutton

this is my first simple app, i am using Xcode 5 iOS7.

My problem is when i press the button a sound is playing but if i press the button when the sound is playing the sound starting from the beginning. I don't know how to fix this, disable the button or if i can code something like this:

```
@implementation ViewController
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
BOOL playing;


if([audioPlayer isPlaying]){
  (playing = NO);
}

else if(playing == NO){
    [audioPlayer play];
    (playing = YES);
    }
```

but this doesn't work :)

Here is the code that i using now.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;


- (void)viewDidLoad

{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
NSURL *audioFile;
audioFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"docka" ofType:@"mp3"]];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFile error:nil];
[audioPlayer play];
}
@end
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is, can you reformulate please? What does you button need to do? Play and pause the AudioPlayer?

Comment: Hello, the button have only need to play the sound, but i don't want the sound to restart if i press the button when a sound already is playing. Do you understand my problem now? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `[yourButton setEnabled:NO];` in your IBAction to play the audio, then call `[yourButton setEnabled:YES];` in the delegate method `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:`. First you'd have to set the delegate for your AVAudioPlayer, and adopt the protocol in your header file, but that should work.